# SQL update and join three tables based on rows in one table and not another

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, join

I have a bit of a complicated sql query I need to do, and I'm a bit stuck. I'm using SQLite if that changes anything.

I have the following table structure:

```
Table G
---------
G_id (primary key) | Other cols ...
====================================
        21
        22
        23
        24
        25
        26
        27 (no g_to_s_map)
        28
```

.

```
Table S
---------
S_id (primary key) |  S_num  | Other cols.....
====================================
        1              1101
        2              1102
        3              1103
        4              1104
        5              1105
        6              1106
        7              1107      (no g_to_s_map, no s_to_t_map)
        8              1108      (no g_to_s_map, there IS an s_to_t_map)
        9              1109      (there is an g_to_s_map, but no s_to_t map)
```

.

```
Table T
---------
T_id (primary key) | Other cols...
==================================
        1
        2
```

Then I also have two mapping tables:

```
Table G_to_S_Map (1:1 mapping, unique values of both g_id and s_id)
----------
G_id (foreign key ref g)| S_id (foreign key ref s)
===================================================
           21                        1  
           22                        2  
           23                        3  
           24                        4  
           25                        5  
           26                        6  
           28                        9
```

.

```
Table S_to_T_Map (many:1 mapping, many unique s_id to a t_id)
----------
S_id (foreign key ref s) | T_id (foreign key ref s)
===================================================
           1                         1    
           2                         1    
           3                         1    
           4                         2    
           5                         2    
           6                         2 
           8                         2
```

Given only a **T_id** and a **G_id**, I need to be able to update the **G_to_S_Map** with the first **S_id** corresponding to the specified **T_id** (in the **S_to_T_Map**) that is NOT in the **G_to_S_Map**

The first thing I was thinking of was just getting any **S_id**'s that corresponded to the **T_id** in the **S_to_T_Map**:

```
SELECT S_id FROM S_to_T_Map where T_id = GIVEN_T_ID;
```

Then presumably I would join those values somehow with the **G_to_S_Map** using a left/right join maybe, and then look for the first value which doesn't exist on one of the sides? Then I'd need to do an insert into the **G_to_S_Map** based on that **S_id** and the **GIVEN_G_ID** value or something.

Any suggestions on how to go about this? Thanks!

---

Edit: Added some dummy data:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
INSERT INTO G_To_S_Map (G_id, S_id) 
          (SELECT :inputGId, a.S_id
           FROM S_To_T_Map as a
           LEFT JOIN G_To_S_Map as b
           ON b.S_id = a.S_id
           AND b.G_id = :inputGId
           WHERE a.T_id = :inputTId
           AND b.G_id IS NULL
           ORDER BY a.S_id
           LIMIT 1);
```

---

EDIT:

If you're wanting to do the order by a different table, use this version:

```
INSERT INTO G_To_S_Map (G_id, S_id) 
          (SELECT :inputGId, a.S_id
           FROM S_To_T_Map as a
           JOIN S as b
           ON b.S_id = a.S_id
           LEFT JOIN G_To_S_Map as c
           ON c.S_id = a.S_id
           AND c.G_id = :inputGId
           WHERE a.T_id = :inputTId
           AND c.G_id IS NULL
           ORDER BY b.S_num
           LIMIT 1);
```

(As an aside, I really hope your tables aren't *actually* named like this, because that's a terrible thing to do.  The use of `Map`, especially, should *probably* be avoided)

---

EDIT:

Here's some example test data.  Have I missed something?  Did I conceptualize the relationships incorrectly?

```
S_To_T_Map
================
S_ID    T_ID    
   1       1    
   2       1    
   3       1    
   1       2    
   1       3    
   3       3 

G_To_S_Map
==================   
G_ID    S_ID  
   1       1  
   3       1  
   2       1  
   3       2  
   2       3  
   3       3
```

Resulting joined data:
(CTEs used to generate cross-join test data)

```
Results:
=============================
G_TEST    T_TEST    S_ID 
     1         1       3 
     2         1       2 
     1         3       3
```

---

EDIT:

Ah, okay, now I get the problem.  My issue was that I was assuming there was some sort of many-one relationship between `S` and `G`.  As this is not the case, use this amended statement:

```
INSERT INTO G_To_S_Map (G_id, S_id)  
      (SELECT :inputGId, a.S_id 
       FROM S_To_T_Map as a 
       JOIN S as b 
       ON b.S_id = a.S_id 
       LEFT JOIN G_To_S_Map as c 
       ON c.S_id = a.S_id 
       OR c.G_id = :inputGId
       WHERE a.T_id = :inputTId 
       AND c.G_id IS NULL 
       ORDER BY b.S_num 
       LIMIT 1);
```

Specficially, the line checking `G_To_S_Map` for a row containing the `G_Id` needed to be switched from using an `AND` to an `OR` - the key requirement *which had not been specified previously* was the fact that both `G_Id` and `S_Id` were unique in `G_To_S_Map`.
This statement will not insert a line if either the provided `G_Id` has been mapped previously, or if all `S_Id`s mapped to the given `T_Id` have been mapped.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks! Why is there an :inputGId in the select of the S_to_T_Map? I assume yours is more efficient than my multiple selects. What if I wanted to ORDER BY a field called "s_Num" in table "S" instead, though?

Comment: I'm using the `:<variableName>` as host variables (I don't know what your syntax looks like).  The reason I use it in the `SELECT` portion is that I'm expecting the resulting references of `G_To_S_Map` to be _null_ - there won't be a reference from a table to use.  Answer edited to include reference to table `S`

Comment: Ah, thanks! Yeah, those are just sanitized variable names, I'd be crazy to use those otherwise :p

Comment: Just wondering, what is this line:  "ON s.id = a.S_id" ? Not sure what s.id was supposed to be. Probably b.s_id though. Also, "cb.G_id = :inputGId" did you mean "c.G_id"?

These variable names are brutal, my bad ;)

Comment: It doesn't appear to work, unforuntately. I get a value that's already in the "g_to_s_map" when I run it with the above changes. It's just giving me the value of the one with the lowest S_num, regardless of whether or not it's in the table.

Comment: @Jordan - Fixed the typos, sorry.  Could you provide some example data and results in your question, if mine doesn't suit?

Comment: The G_to_S_map is a 1:1 relationship between G and S (unique values of each), but the S_to_T map is a many:1 relationship. There can be multiple S_id that have the same T_id, but only unique S_id in the table. I added some more information about the relationships between the tables in my original post.

Comment: Corrected for more specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the following seems to work nicely, although I haven't combined an "insert" with it yet.

```
Select s.S_ID from S as s 
inner join(
    Select st.S_ID from s_to_t_map as st 
    where st.T_ID=???? AND not exists
                    (Select * from g_to_s_Map as gs where gs.S_ID = st.S_ID)
 ) rslt on s.S_ID=rslt.S_ID  ORDER BY s.s_Num ASC limit 1;
```

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY`, you're getting a 'random' row.  And stop using 'update', which has a _very_ specific meaning in SQL.  Tagging out to table `S` is pointless, as I would assume you have the necessary fk references.

Comment: Yeah, I have an ORDER BY in my syntax, just took it out for the purposes of this. And yeah, I meant "insert" and not "update", forgot that the entry wouldn't have existed yet.